# Retrieving data from Firebase Real time database into Recycler View using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter for the first time so I am unable to to use it and facing some issues and unable to show any data on the screen
[image: This image shows the structure of the database]
The code for the HomeFragment is below

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link HomeFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ProductAdapter adapter;

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Product> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Product>()
                .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()), Product.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new ProductAdapter(options);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

The code for ProductAdapter is

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;

public class ProductAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

    public ProductAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Product> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Product model) {
        holder.pname.setText(model.getPname());
        holder.price.setText(model.getPrice());
        holder.description.setText(model.getDescription());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);

        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView pname, price, description;
        ImageView image;
        public ProductViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            pname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_list_name);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_list_price);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_list_description);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
        }
    }
}
```

The code of Product class is below

```
public class Product {
    String pname,price,description,image,date,category,pid,time;
    private boolean expanded;

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(String pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String pname, String price, String description, String image, String date, String category, String pid, String time) {
        this.pname = pname;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
        this.date = date;
        this.category = category;
        this.pid = pid;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getPname() {
        return pname;
    }

    public void setPname(String pname) {
        this.pname = pname;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return expanded;
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "pname='" + pname + '\'' +
                ", price='" + price + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", image='" + image + '\'' +
                ", expanded=" + expanded +
                '}';
    }
}
```

So I want to retrieve The product details from the Real time database and want to show in a fragment as list of different products

Comment: If you try to log the value of `model.getPname()`, is it something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes the name of the product (i.e. xyz) gets printed in the logcat.

Comment: Have you tried to make the fields in your `Product` class private? Does it work this way?

Comment: @AlexMamo but I have to access these fields from ProductAdapter class..So how can I make these fields private? When I made these fields private this error is displayed while building gradle                                                                            `error: getPname() has private access in Product
holder.pname.setText(model.getPname());`

Comment: Try to make the fields private not the getters. Getters should always be public.

Comment: @AlexMamo that I have done..but still the problem exists

Answer (score 0):

**I am guessing that you have extra fields in your `Product` class:**

**In your `Product` class:**

Remove this field:

```
private boolean expanded;
```

Remove these also:

```
public boolean isExpanded() {
    return expanded;
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
    this.expanded = expanded;
}
```

Comment: Sir I have done that but then also it is not showing